# La autorización del encabezado no llega | NextJs SSR - Amplify custom headers JWT

Tags: headers, nextjs, yml, jsonwebtoken, amplify

En localhost y Vercel, funciona perfectamente.
El token de autorización básico no llega a la configuración del *middleware* de NodeJS. Probé muchos encabezados en `customHttp.yml`, también busqué cualquier impresión en AWS CloudWatch, pero no tuve éxito, así que necesito su ayuda.
Este es el método que hace la solicitud:

```
export const postData = async(url, post, token) => {
const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/${url}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(post),
});

const data = await res.json();
return data;
```

};

Aquí tengo el token JWT:

[image: Here I got the authorization token]

Y este es mi archivo `customHttp.yml` para configurar los encabezados personalizados para Amplificar:

```
  customHeaders:
  - pattern: "**/*"
    headers:
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        value: "*"
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        value: "*"
      - key: authorization
        value: $token
      - key: Content-Type
        value: application/json
```

[image: customHttp.yml]

Por favor ayuda, es el reto de mi vida :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volví a crear mi app amplify con el siguiente YAML y funcionó perfecto:

```
customHeaders:
```

- pattern: "**/*"
  headers:

  - key: Access-Control-Allow-Headers
    value: "*"
  - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    value: "*"
  - key: authorization
    value: $token